# Copy named ranges from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook A which has three named ranges Alpha, Beta, Charlie.
I would like to copy values of those name ranges to Workbook B which is stored in the SharePoint location. Workbook B also has three named ranges Alpha, Beta, Charlie.
Workbook A is not stored in the SharePoint and it comes in named differently each time so I cannot predefine it's name whereas Workbook B always has the same name.

I tried below example.

```
Sub CopyPaste() 
    Dim sourceWb As Workbook
    Dim openWb As Workbook
        
    Set openWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="https://SharePointLocationToWorkbookB.xlsm ", ReadOnly:=False, UpdateLinks:=False)
    sourceWb.Range("Alpha").Value = openWb("sheet1").Range("Alpha").Value
    sourceWb.Range("Beta").Value = openWb("sheet1").Range("Beta").Value
    sourceWb.Range("Charlie").Value = openWb("sheet1").Range("Charlie").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `sourceWb.Range()` you should have a worksheet reference in there...  FYI "it's not working" is not a very useful description of the actual problem you're having with your code.

Comment: @Chronocidal I don't think it's reverse. I'm putting the values from Workbook A openWb into Workbook B (sourceWb). Workbook A is an active workbook currently open

Comment: @MetaTag Sorry; for some reason I mixed up the `openWb` and `sourceWb` when reading the `Set` lines…

Comment: If source has workbook focus, than you can do `Source.Names("Alpha").RefersToRange` instead of `sourceWb.Range("Alpha")` (you cannot use range with a workbook). Also, you need to use `openWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")` in stead of `openWb("sheet1")`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sourceWb` is confusingly-named...  Maybe try something like this:

```vb
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, destWs As Worksheet, rn
    
    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set destWs = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="https://SharePointLocationToWorkbookB.xlsm", _
                    ReadOnly:=False, UpdateLinks:=False).Worksheets("Sheet1") 'for example
    
    For Each rn In Array("Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie")
        destWs.Range(rn).Value = sourceWs.Range(rn).Value
    Next rn
    
    destWs.Parent.Close True 'save changes
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks your solution works great. One question how could I change your code if name ranges in both workbook were not matching?

Comment: If they're not matching then you'd need two array - one for the source names, and one for the destination names.  Or use a table on a worksheet to list the sources and destinations, and loop over that.  The "best" approach might depend on how many cells you need to transfer.